# Convert inequality to equality

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, inequalities

I have $ineq=x+y+1>0$, I need to extract $eq=x+y+1$ from it, how can I do this?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Everything is an expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html), [Parts of expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PartsOfExpressions.html) and the tutorials linked from the latter (top right of the page)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing the question, but you can just grab the part of the inequality that you need. In this case, the thing you want to be `eq` is the first part:

```
ineq = x + y + 1 > 0;
eq = ineq[[1]]
```